cannot use await in async function in rust
I have this code

#[api_operation(
    tag = "image",
    summary = "uploads an image",
    description = r###"upload an image to an account"###,
    error_code = 405
)]
pub async fn upload_image(mut payload: Multipart) -> impl Responder {
    let upload_dir = std::env::var("UPLOAD_DIR").unwrap_or_else(|_| "./uploads".to_string());

    let upload_status = files::save_file(payload, format!("{upload_dir}/test.png").to_string()).await;

which to me looks like an async method.
but for some reason I am getting compile errors
error[E0728]: `await` is only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks
  --> src/image.rs:18:97
   |
9  | / #[api_operation(
10 | |     tag = "image",
11 | |     summary = "uploads an image",
12 | |     description = r###"upload an image to an account"###,
13 | |     error_code = 405
14 | | )]
   | |__- this is not `async`
...
18 |       let upload_status = files::save_file(payload, format!("{upload_dir}/test.png").to_string()).await;
   |                                                                                                   ^^^^^ only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks


is it saying that the macro is causing it not to be async, or why can't I use await?
and is there any way around it?

What's api_operation? How is it defined/ what crate is it from?

Presumably api_operation is rewriting the function to be non-async, but it's impossible to tell without knowing what crate it's from.

It is from apistos https://github.com/netwo-io/apistos/

Please [edit] your question to include all necessary information, don't answer in comments.

What's most likely happening is this function isn't valid for the macro, but the macro isn't properly erroring. Or the macro is simply broken. You should file an issue with the crate it's from, either to improve documentation or fix the bug.

@drewtato one would hope it would work since their docs show the macro used on an async function (though suspiciously they don't actually await anything in the examples). I concur with filing a issue.

I can't compile and run this code even after adding the apistos dependency. There's no clue where Multipart/Responder come from, nor what files is. Please create a [mre].

I looked into it a little and created an issue. The macro expands to a regular closure wrapping the body.

This was a bug in the apistos::api_operation macro, it has since been resolved and your code does work with versions that include the corresponding code changes
